# How only use filename after file downloaded in webview

Tags: android, webview

I try use "`setdownloadlistener`" for `webview` can download file from web and its work but my problem is after i click download file like example.pdf file and file download with different name not original name like this after download name change to "download.bin" but the original name is "example.pdf" how to "`setdownloadlistener`" to use the original name. this code i use for download

```
webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimeType, long contentLength) {
                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
                try {
                    request.setMimeType(mimeType);
                    //------------------------COOKIE!!------------------------
                    String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
                    request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookies);
                    //------------------------COOKIE!!------------------------
                    request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
                    request.setDescription("Downloading file...");
                    request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
                    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
                    DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                    dm.enqueue(request);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading File", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error Downloading File.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

thanks

Comment: your code is working properly .Please check the url you are using .

Comment: @sankalp, no problem with my url, because if i open in default browser the filename is correct.